# WINSDK: Determining whether an arbitrary pid identifies a running process on Windows

Tags: windows, security, process, winapi

Attempting to implement a poor man's test of whether a process is still running or not (essentially an equivalent of the trivial `kill(pid, 0)`.)

Hoped to be able to simply call `OpenProcess` with some minimal desired access then test for either `GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` or `GetExitCodeProcess(...) != STILL_ACTIVE`.

Nice try...  Running on Windows XP, as administrator:

```
HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
if (!hProc) {
  DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
}
```

...fails miserably with `dwLastError == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when `pid` is owned by a different (not SYSTEM) user.  Moreover, if `pid` *was* originally owned by a different user but has since terminated, `OpenProcess` also fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (not `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.)

Do I have to use `Process32First`/`Process32Next` or `EnumProcesses`?

I absolutely **do not want to use `SeDebugPrivilege`**.

Thanks,
V

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591342/how-to-determine-if-a-windows-process-is-running which may have some other more reliable methods

Comment: @rogerdpack in this case the only available information is the `pid`.  No handle is available.  I know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591342/how-to-determine-if-a-windows-process-is-running , I even contributed a comment or two there. :)

Comment: yes, more I was making the comment to alert users that I'd added an answer that that might work for this question, as well, but didn't want to add it to both places. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
static BOOL
isProcessAlive(DWORD th32ProcessID) {
  BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

  HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { sizeof(pe32), 0 };
    if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe32)) {
      while (pe32.th32ProcessID != pid && Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32));
      _ASSERT(GetLastError() == 0 || GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES);
      bSuccess = (pe32.th32ProcessID == th32ProcessID);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
  }
  return bSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a process ID:

```
// this should succeed even when a medium integrity process
// requests access to a high integrity process
if (HANDLE h = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid))
{
    // do a wait, if the handle is signaled: not running
    DWORD wait = WaitForSingleObject(h, 0);
    if (wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0) return FALSE;
}
// cannot get a handle to the process:
// probably running at system integrity level
// I'm not sure how reliable this check is, but it seems to work:
// if access is denied: running
// if invalid parameter: not running
else if (GetLastError() != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) return FALSE;
```

If you have a window handle that should be valid for as long as the process is running, this is a good alternative:

```
if (hWnd && !IsWindow(hWnd)) return FALSE;
```

Comment: Was this fixed after Windows XP?  "if `pid` was originally owned by a different user but has since terminated, `OpenProcess` also fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (not `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.)"