# How to get HANDLE for an application

Tags: visual-c++, winapi, mfc

How to get HANDLE for an application say Outlook from my program

Comment: process HANDLE or window (HWND)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a process handle by its name in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the process id of the process you want to get the handle for and use [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here's an example for this as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: +1 for answering the question that the OP actually wanted answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use WIN32 API [FindWindow()](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32FindWindow.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Probably try this:

```
HANDLE hOutlook = FindWindow("rctrl_renwnd32", NULL);
```