# How can I close an application using my program?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to disable Norton auto protect. I don't actually want to close the program. If you click on the Norton icon it gives you the option to disable it.

I would like to write a program that clicks the button for me. I am just not sure how to go about this. I am using C++ and I have Visual Studio and Windows XP.

Comment: your question is vague..Explain the question well?

Comment: Instead of clicking on the icon and pressing disable I want a program that does this for me. So I want an automated process or script.

Comment: give the programming language that is used to create this application.Mention some details about your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling another program in windows task pane automated process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172288/disabling-another-program-in-windows-task-pane-automated-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to close an application or disable an application (like disable java update etc)? If you are talking about closing an application using your program, you can use "TerminateProcess()".

If you are talking about disabling application, share with us particular use-case exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to disable norton auto protect, I don't actually want to close the program. If you click on the Norton icon it gives you the option to disable it. I would like to write a program that so to say clicks the button for me. I am just not sure how to go about this. I am using c++ and I have visual studio and windows xp.

Comment: @Welf I think the name of Norton auto protect process is "navapsvc.exe". anyway, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

Comment: @Welf - If it was easy for a program to disable Norton, any virus would do that. I think it requires user interaction.

Comment: @welf - I changed your question to your comment, you should be more to the point rather than have folks trying to second guess/mind read :) Thanks.