# getting a module handle from other process

Tags: c++, module

Is there a way to get the handle of a module which I know its name from another process using C++?
`GetModuleHandle` and `GetModuleHandleEx` are good only getting the handle from the same process.

Comment: CreateToolhelp32Snapshot + Module32First/Next

Comment: There is an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c  from a previous post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** and **[PEB_LDR_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

```
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {
  BYTE       Reserved1[8];
  PVOID      Reserved2[3];
  LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```

The LIST_ENTRY is a linked list that contains your dll name and base address of where the dll is loaded.

```
typedef struct _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY {
    PVOID Reserved1[2];
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderLinks;
    PVOID Reserved2[2];
    PVOID DllBase;
    PVOID EntryPoint;
    PVOID Reserved3;
    UNICODE_STRING FullDllName;
    BYTE Reserved4[8];
    PVOID Reserved5[3];
    union {
        ULONG CheckSum;
        PVOID Reserved6;
    };
    ULONG TimeDateStamp;
} LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, *PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY;
```