# GetModuleHandle() cannot retrieve handle of "advapi32.dll" loaded by "notepad.exe"

Tags: c++, winapi, reverse-engineering, notepad

I am trying to get file information handled by notepad.exe.

So, my program does the following steps.

1. Create process for notepad.exe

   `CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);`
2. Wait until finish initialization of notepad.exe

   `WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, 10000);`
3. Attach notepad.exe process to my program as Debugee.

   `DebugActiveProcess(dwPID)`
4. Wait for debug event from Debugee.
5. When my program receive `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`, doing something I need.

Here is my function having an issue.

```
LPVOID g_pfHookingAdd = NULL;
BOOL OnCreateProcessDebugEvent(LPDEBUG_EVENT pde)
{
    DWORD dwLastErr;
    if (NULL == GetModuleHandleA("advapi32.dll"))   // Not able to get a handle here.
    {
        dwLastErr = GetLastError(); // dwLastErr => 126 => (0x7E) 
    }
    g_pfHookingAdd = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("advapi32.dll"), "IsTextUnicode");
    return TRUE;
}
```

As you can see, my goal is to retrieve the address where `IsTextUnicode()` function is loaded.

However, when I call `GetModuleHandleA("advapi32.dll")`, I get error code 126, which is
`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.

I also checked that `advapi32.dll` is loaded during the notepad.exe execution.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Here is my environmental conditions:

Windows 10 pro version 1803 (OS build 17134.165)

Comment: You are pretty lucky that your program did not load advapi32.dll.  Goal is murky, but when you write a debugger then you need to learn how to use [the DbgHelp api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/debug-help-library).

Comment: for what you need `GetModuleHandle` if you got `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` ? and for what you call `DebugActiveProcess` instead just create process with flag `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` ?

Comment: I am trying to get a first byte data where function loaded. Actually it is my another issue to solve, when I create process with flag `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` or `DEBUG_PROCESS`, I cannot get a right data from [`memcpy(&g_cpdi, &pde->u.CreateProcessInfo, sizeof(CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO));
 ReadProcessMemory(g_cpdi.hProcess, g_pfHookingAdd, &g_chOrgByte, sizeof(BYTE), NULL);`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't working because [GetModuleHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) ...

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. The module must
>   have been loaded by the calling process.

Answers to [GetModuleHandle(), for a DLL in another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395243/getmodulehandle-for-a-dll-in-another-process) might help you.

Comment: Thank for your quick answer. So do you mean advapi32.dll is not loaded by notepad.exe directly?

Comment: @Lance please read my answer again. `GetoduleHanle()` fails because `advapi32.dll` is loaded by `notepad.exe` and not your program that is executing `GetModuleHandle()`.

Comment: OMG I had been totally misunderstood about GetModuleHandle. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good diagnosis, but it actually makes this question a duplicate of the one you found.

Comment: @BenVoigt well, i guess there is no harm done by answering this question albeit it is a duplicate.

Comment: Well, actually we think that linking to duplicates is better