# How to ask to restart firefox?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have created a c++ program that install also a firefox extension. So, to get this extension works, he need to restart firefox.

So, how can I ask to restart firefox while the user is using it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of looks like a duplicate to this question: [winapi - How can I get a process handle by its name in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c). Essentially, what you'd be looking to do is "find" the process "firefox.exe" (in place of "target.exe") and if finding it is successful, you put up a warning dialogue box to close firefox and re-open. If not, you just continue with the install or whatever. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Find the main window of Firefox using its caption. I guess Firefox appends the title of the current page to the caption of the main window, so `FindWindow` is not enough. Try to enumerate top-level windows using `EnumWindows`, and find the one containing "Mozilla Firefox" in the caption. If you have the window handle, send a `WM_CLOSE` message to it (use `PostMessage` which waits for the target window to process the message), and wait for it to disappear. You may get a popup, find and close it the same way. If the main Firefox window is still open after a few seconds (try to find it repeatedly), you may call `TerminateProcess` (you will need `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `OpenProcess` for this). When the window is closed, restart Firefox by calling `CreateProcess`. (There are lots of examples for all these API functions on the Web.)