# Sending signals to applications (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, api, signals, mutex

I'm going crazy thinking how to send signals to an external .exe on Windows with C++.
A guy "user1764961", suggested to use Mutex but I don't really understand how it works!
I was also reading this page: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_signal_handling.htm
But I don't understand...

For example: I would like to send a closing signal to a "no window" .exe
I know everything about the .exe if there are details required.

Comment: What is a closing signal? That term is not in common use. Forget all about signals and tell us what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want to terminate a process (a running application) with a DLL, but the application before closing need to stop recording a video stream.

Comment: It sounds like you should use the automation API to do this.

Comment: For your purpose an named event object (`CreateEvent`) should be better.  But note it won't interrupt what your program is doing; it can only be detected when you enter a wait (you can poll using a wait with instant timeout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Nor elegantest nor safest (very very unsafe) but the simpliest way to solve your problem.

In application to be closed do this:

```
DWORD dwProcessID;
HANDLE hProcess, hMutex;
hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
DuplicateHandle(hProcess, hProcess, hProcess, &hProcess, NULL, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
// write retrieved handle somewhere in file. let it be "C:\sample.txt"
// ...
hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, L"Look at me! I'm a scarry MUTEX");
//... Your code
// go close your video streams or do whatever you want
// ...
ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
```

In your app:

```
// so now the distant proc works and you now it
// it is time to terminate it.
HANDLE hMutex, hProcess;
// read hProcess from "C:\sample.txt" 
hMutex = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, L"Look at me! I'm scary MUTEX");
WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE); //if your "video app" will not release the mutex you will wait forever.
TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0); //that's what you need
```

Mutex is a core object. You can think of it as of traffic light manipulated by owner. And pedestrians should obey it if they want to get on the over side of road alive.

In given example are 2 opened problems.

First is you shouldn't write process handle in file. How to get process handle then? Well, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c).

Secondly as I said before you can't wait forever unless you are god. Be sure that your process will release mutex or set  `WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, TIME_INTERVAL)`. TIME_INTERVAL is DWORD. Just choose it.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: You aren't signalling the other process to close gracefully, you're nuking it from orbit with `TerminateProcess`.  That doesn't seem to be what the question is looking for.

Comment: No it's not what I was asking for but it's the best example of mutex I found! I think I can apply it. Or silply do something like this:
HWND hWnd = FindWindow("recoder_app", NULL);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);

Comment: And in the Recorder application I save the stream on the WM_CLOSE case.

Comment: @Edoardo All right, if your app got window you should use 'PostMessage'. Btw, there's another good kernel object you might need: Semaphore. Microsoft provides us a nice written [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx) on it.