# Finding process name by PID

Tags: winapi, ctypes, python-3.5

I'm using the ctypes module and WinAPI to find the process name by PID.
I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/865201/249552) example written in C/C++ and it's working except for the fact that the size of my `szExeFile` is 0 for every process. Am I missing something while using this API?

```
def find_pid_with_name(process_name: str):
    entry = PROCESSENTRY32()
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)

    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, None)

    if Process32First(snapshot, byref(entry)) == TRUE:
        while Process32Next(snapshot, byref(entry)) == TRUE:
            print(libc.wcslen(entry.szExeFile))

    CloseHandle(snapshot)
```

My structure definition for `PROCESSENTRY32`:

```
MAX_PATH = 260
class PROCESSENTRY32(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwSize", c_ulong),
        ("cntUsage", c_ulong),
        ("th32ProcessID", c_ulong),
        ("th32DefaultHeapID", POINTER(c_ulong)),
        ("th32ModuleId", c_ulong),
        ("cntThreads", c_ulong),
        ("th32ParentProcessID", c_ulong),
        ("dwFlags", c_ulong),
        ("szExeFile", c_wchar * MAX_PATH)
    ]
```

And my function definitions:

```
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = windll.kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = [c_ulong, POINTER(c_ulong)]
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = c_ulong

libc = CDLL("msvcrt")
libc.wcslen.argtypes = [c_wchar_p]

Process32First = windll.kernel32.Process32First
Process32First.argtypes = [c_ulong, POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32)]
Process32First.restype = c_ubyte

Process32Next = windll.kernel32.Process32Next
Process32Next.argtypes = [c_ulong, POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32)]
Process32Next.restype = c_ubyte
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See definition for [`PROCESSENTRY32W`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx)

Yours is missing `pcPriClassBase`

```
("dwSize", c_ulong),
("cntUsage", c_ulong),
("th32ProcessID", c_ulong),
("th32DefaultHeapID", POINTER(c_ulong)),
("th32ModuleId", c_ulong),
("cntThreads", c_ulong),
("th32ParentProcessID", c_ulong),
("pcPriClassBase" , c_long),<=======
("dwFlags", c_ulong),
("szExeFile", c_wchar * MAX_PATH)
```

Also try the following fo return type and arg type

```
Process32First.argtypes = [ c_void_p , POINTER( PROCESSENTRY32 ) ]
Process32First.rettype = c_int

Process32Next.argtypes = [ c_void_p , POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32) ]
Process32Next.rettype = c_int
```

Note, in WinAPI `BOOL` is a macro for `int`, `HANDLE` is a macro for `void*`

The C++ source which you are using is missing the first entry. It's supposed to use a do-while loop instead. You can deal with that later. For example:

```
HANDLE handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (handle)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(handle, &process);
    do
    {
        std::wcout << process.szExeFile << "\n";
    } while (Process32Next(handle, &process));
    CloseHandle(handle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much; and thank you for pointing out the use of the do-while loop.