# Why cannot execute "taskkill" from cmd in c++?

Tags: c++, cmd, administration, runas, taskkill

I want to execute `taskkill` from cmd in c++ code. I have tried two forms:

1. Simple form:

```
system("taskkill /IM 'example.exe' /F");
```

2. With administrative privilege (because one of my processes has high privilege):

```
system("runas / profile / user:administrator \"taskkill /IM 'exmaple.exe' /F\"");
```

Also my c++ program was run as administrator.
But none of these commands executed successfully. What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you use system? Windows has an API method for that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess.

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes around example.exe: `'example.exe'` -> `example.exe`.

Comment: Have you tried running these commands directly and seeing if they work?

Comment: What I mean is that if you use the API you will be able to get much better error information on why it fails.

Comment: @wohlstand Thanks, but the result does not changed.

Comment: @chris It was successful

Comment: @sh.sagheb this is strange. I launched notepad.exe, and tried (in a cmd.exe terminal): `taskkill /IM 'notepad.exe' /F` and got `ERROR: The process "'notepad.exe'" not found.`. Then I tried `taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F` and it succeeded (got: `SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID ... has been terminated.`). It also worked when I enclosed notepad.exe with double-quotes (`"`). But not with single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate fix could be to remove the single quotes (`'`) enclosing `example.exe`.
E.g. instead of:

```
system("taskkill /IM 'example.exe' /F");
```

Use:

```
system("taskkill /IM example.exe /F");
```

Using double quotes (`"` - escaped in this case with `\`) is also OK:

```
system("taskkill /IM \"example.exe\" /F");
```

**However** -
As commented above by @PepijnKramer, you can use dedicated windows API functions to do the same.
This requires a bit more code, but offers much better control and feedback of errors.

Here's an outline of what you need to do:

1. Get the process PID from its name (see below).
2. Open the process using [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) API to aqcuire a handle to it, with `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access right (see below).

An example of getting PID and then a handle to a process by its name: [How can I get a process handle by its name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c).

3. Use the handle with [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) API to kill the process.
   Note that in order to use it:

> The handle must have the PROCESS_TERMINATE access right.

*(this should be passed to `OpenProcess` via the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter)*.